# Creating association classes on Visio 2019

Tags: uml, project, visio

I'm a beginner using Visio. For my project, I'm using the 2019 Professional version and I'm having a trouble to create an association class, like the "Items", down in the image.

[image: example case]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To draw a dashed line from a class to an association, proceed as follows:

1. Click with the right mouse button on the background of the drawing. A toolbar and a menu pop up at the same time.
2. The top left button of the toolbar has a very small triangle next to it, pointing down. Click on this triangle. A menu drops down.
3. Choose 'line' from this menu (it's the fifth entry).
4. Drag a line from the class to the association. A solid line will appear.
5. Click with the right mouse button on the line and choose 'Format shape'. The Format shape pane will appear.
6. In the Format shape pane, choose dashed formatting.